# Azure APIM Instance - Failed to update API management service hostnames

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

I am trying to update APIM custom domains with new certificates from the KeyVault. But it fails with the message "Failed to update  API management service hostnames" with some CorrelationID.

I tried to delete the domain from the custom domain list, still the same here. Has anyone faced similar issue? Any leads will be helpful.

Comment: Makes sense to open a support ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue.

So basically, I had two custom domains for which the certificates were expired. I was trying to update one of them with new certificate. But it failed all the time.

So the solution is delete all the custom domains that have expired certificates, save them and add the domains again with new certificates.

Answer (score 0):

> Failed to update API management service hostnames

- This error usually occurs when you try to use an Azure Key Vault certificate to add a custom domain to your API Management service.
- This is because the API Management service does not have permission to access the key vault for the custom domain you're trying to use.
- You can refer this [MSFT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-troubleshoot-cannot-add-custom-domain), where one of the work around for this type of error is given.

Comment: I already checked that the API Management has access to Azure Key Vault.